# ¿Cómo enviar un mail en una fecha específica con PHP?

Tags: php, mail

¿puedo enviar mails de esa manera? Por ejemplo, para el cliente necesito que el Lunes por la mañana de la siguiente semana le llegue un mail de recordatorio de una cita, ¿como lo logro?

En Nodejs existe el modulo [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule), no sé si exista algo similar para PHP

Mi código sencillo: `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` donde cada variable es asignado con valores exactos.

Comment: Podrías crear un CRON que ejecute un PHP. Podes configurar el CRON para que ejecute todos los dias, a cada hora o cada X mins. El PHP tendría que chequear si es el día/hora/min es en que se debe enviar el mail.

Comment: Funciona para servidores sencillos con cpanel? pues mi proyecto es algo sencillo con php puro

Comment: Si, solo tenes que buscar dentro del CPanel "cron" y vas a encontrar el modulo para administrarlos.